# Change textbox colour upon correct letter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a crossword using WPF. All my text boxes are red, but I want them to change to green when a certain textbox contains the correct word.

Could anybody help, please?

Comment: look into Style triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bind` your `TextBox`'s `Background` to a `string` property, let's name it `Word`

Then use a `ValueConverter` to convert the `Word` to a `Color`, let's name it `WordColorConverter` (which is a class implementing `IValueConverter`)

Your xaml would look like this assuming it's in a `Window` and you place the `WordColorConverter` in the your `local` namespace

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:WordColorConverter x:Key="WordColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Word}",
               Background="{Binding Word, Converter={StaticResource WordColorConverter}}"/><</
</Grid>
```

And your WordColorConverter class would look something like this...

```
class WordColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string word = (string)value;
            if (word.Equals("correct word"))
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: you could try this for `MultiBinding`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InputWord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WordColorConverter}">
            <Binding Path="InputWord" />
            <Binding Path="CorrectWord" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

```
   public class WordColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string inputWord = (string)values[0];
            string correctWord = (string)values[1];
            if (inputWord.Equals(correctWord))
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this solution is pretty clever, I think it's only half the story. It would be better if you could **pass in** a word which would make this converter much more useful. I propose making use of `CommandParameter` and pass in the desired word.

Comment: Thanks! What if I have to read and convert from a file? Let's say a .txt file is my database for the crossword?

Comment: @Daniel, you have some options. Mike Eason suggested `CommandParameter`. You could also look at `MultiBinding`.

Comment: well it kind of worked, but it doesn't seem to update the textbox's background when I input a text and change it. Although, I appreciate your answer, thanks !

Comment: @Daniel Glad I could help! I tried it myself and it's working fine. Did you assign the `DataContext` to a class with string properties `InputWord` and `CorrectWord` ?

Comment: <Window.DataContext>
        <local:WordColorConverter>
    </Window.DataContext> this?

If so, I did, and the textbox still remains the same. I used correctWord = "correct word" , but the background will always stay red. Doesn't change if I input the "correct word" in the textbox while the program is running. Ty again ha

Comment: No, it's not like that. You should look up `data binding` for `wpf`

Comment: Alright. Last thing I am confused about is that I have to make let's say 20 text boxes for the crossword. How do I set the value of correct word so it compares with what is input in each textbox? Is it the way you put it `correctWord = "A" `

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=aCertainTextBox, Path=Text}" Value="CorrectWord">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

This looks at the value of "aCertainTextbox", if the textbox text is "CorrectWord" it sets the color of the text to green, any other word it should be red. Obviously you'll need to change the names of "ACertainTextBox" and "CorrectWord" to the actual word you want ant the real name of "aCertainTextbox"